# JQuery UI Sortable, Input box not Editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to put an `input` box in a `sortable UL.`

The sortable works but the text is `"locked"` or the `click event is overridden`...not sure what to do.

I think this [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-sortable-disableselection-firefox-issue-with-inputs) addresses some of my issue.  But, I am still confused.

I have also [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skillilea/L22dE/4/) code here for testing.

Thanks Tons In Advance!

sk

Comment: include input in cancel option of the sortable method --   cancel: ".fixed,input"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As pointed in comment, this works when you include input tag in cancel option

```
    $('#jqParetoEditList').sortable({
    cancel: ".fixed,input",
    delay: 100,
    //connectWith: "",
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        //p.HandleSortPareto(ui, ui.item)  // note this just handles the change in order
    },
    start: function (event, ui) {}
});
```

[**Check the Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L22dE/6/)